# Autofac scope is not declared

Tags: c#, vb.net, autofac

I am following the instructions here:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html

But the following line I get "Scope is not declared"

```
Dim myClass As MyClass = scope.Resolve(Of MyClass)(New NamedParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName"))
```

or:

```
var myClass = scope.Resolve<MyClass>(new NamedParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName"));
```

This is within a code behind file, and i am just trying to pass a parameter to a constructor.

Any suggestions, in C# or VB.net or just a pointer on what may be wrong

Comment: Can you post more of the `scope` code? especially init and registering.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.
I have added Autofac.web NuGet package, added the modules to web.config, in global.asax I added the IContainerProvider, and in application_start I build up the container.
However, this constructor requires a pamamater.
So, in my code where the "MyClass" would normally be instantiated ,  I added the code above (based on the link at the top of my question).
FYI, i have a feeling the answer will be something simple... like i have missed one step, im just not sure what step I have missed (seeing as "scope" object doest exist

Comment: My guess its because the scope has not been initialized,

Comment: could be, based on the documentation, I see no initialization of an object called "scope", so i tried to see if importing anything would help.
How do i initialize "scope"? and where?  (seems to be missing from any documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question edit, this solution is **c#** based:

It looks like you have not build your builder with `Build()` or did not registered the the `MyClass` like it should.

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register((c, p) => new MyClass(p.Named<string>("configSectionName")));
```

Now just build the container:

```
IContainer scope = builder.Build();

MyClass log = scope.Resolve<MyClass>(new NamedParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName"));
```

Comment: Thank you
Can the build of the container go in the business logic? (e.g. if i am instantiating a user class, so in constructor i pass in a "userID", this will change based on what user we are viewing.
So i cant do that in the global.asax.  
so i will need to "build" each time i need to pass in a value to a constructor?

Comment: My answer is purely about constructing in runtime (during the `Resolve<>`), e.g inside the business logic so it possible and you are on the right way Just `Register` should be inside the global.asax.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps.  I have marked it as the answer and marked as useful (my rep is to low to show the rate up).
Quick question i hope you don't mind me asking... is it bad practice to "builder.build" and "resolve" at runtime when ever you need to?
(or will it be better to create a method to pass a value in that will setup the user object (instead of using the constructor?
... I could raise this as another question if its worth doing so

Comment: There is no right answer to this, it is all depends upon your logic, I suggest you to raise a question regarding your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work for me : (
My class is within a class library project and I cant access global.asax "builder" from within it to allow me to "Resolve" from within the class library

Comment: You will need to make the builder available globaly

Comment: using a session?

Comment: I managed to adjust IoC so i can use the webform.aspx page.  I have other classes that may need to access the builder, however, from what I have read, if IoC setup correctly, i shouldnt need to be accessing the container from within my class library

Comment: can you post a url ?

Comment: My readings were from various places, but here is how I am currently doing it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576150/webforms-autofac-parameter-to-constructor-using-vb-net/54579400#54579400
Are you having problems with accessing the container in a class library? (Ill probably be looking into that soon also, can post details here if I find solution)